# INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED - firebase error in React JS while adding document to the collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on creating a chat app using React JS and Firebase in which I have a collection of groups within which we have separate collection of messages for each group. For adding a new group in Firestore, it works fine, but when I am adding a new message to the respective collection it's showing this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: FIRESTORE (8.8.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected 
state
at O (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:287)
at ce (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:1978)
at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:1957
at comparator (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:11535)
at t.insert (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:2825)
at t.insert (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:2668)
at t.add (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:11579)
at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:12042
at t.inorderTraversal (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:2802)
at t.inorderTraversal (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:2720)
at t._o (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:12016)
at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:12338
at step (tslib.es6.js:102)
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83)
at tslib.es6.js:76
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:72)
at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:12333
at t.Oo (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:12357)
at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:12808
at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:6794
at G (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:598)
at t.forEach (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:6791)
at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:12807
at step (tslib.es6.js:102)
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83)
at tslib.es6.js:76
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:72)
at Ys (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:12802)
at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:12462
at step (tslib.es6.js:102)
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83)
at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:73)
```

I have searched all over the internet and came to know that the `timeStamp` might have created the issue. Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Here's my code for the same:

```
const ChatInput = ({ roomId }) => {
const [showKeyboard, setShowKeyboard] = useState(false);
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
const emoRef = useRef(null);

const onEmojiClick = (event, emojiObject) => {
    setMessage(message + emojiObject?.emoji);
};

// useEffect(() => {
//  if (message === '') {
//      inputRef.current.focus();
//  }
// }, []);

const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // console.log(message);

    db.collection('rooms').doc(roomId).collection('messages').add({
        message,
        user: 'Remy Sharp',
        userImage:
            'https://www.webxcreation.com/event-recruitment/images/profile-1.jpg',
        timeStamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });

    setMessage('');
};

return (
    <ChatInputWrapper>
        <Tooltip title="Emoji" TransitionComponent={Zoom}>
            <Emoji onClick={() => setShowKeyboard(!showKeyboard)}>
                <InsertEmoticonIcon />
            </Emoji>
        </Tooltip>
        <EmojiKeyboard ref={emoRef} show={showKeyboard}>
            <Picker onEmojiClick={onEmojiClick} />
        </EmojiKeyboard>

        <ChatForm onSubmit={sendMessage}>
            <ChatText
                value={message}
                onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Type a message ..."
            />
            <Tooltip title="Send" TransitionComponent={Zoom}>
                <ChatSend type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}>
                    <SendIcon />
                </ChatSend>
            </Tooltip>
        </ChatForm>
    </ChatInputWrapper>
);
};

export default ChatInput;
```

Here is the firebase.js :

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: '',
authDomain: '',
projectId: '',
storageBucket: '',
messagingSenderId: '',
appId: '1::web:',
measurementId: 'G',
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

Comment: Just an Edit , It works fine without timeStamp . But I need timeStamp , so please help with that .

Answer (score 2):

This is because by doing

```
export { db, auth, provider };
```

you don't export `firebaseApp` (nor `firebase`) and therefore

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

generates an error.

---

I suggest you do as follows:

**In firebase.js:**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
var firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const fv = firebase.firestore.fieldValue;  // <=
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, fv, auth, provider };
```

**When writing to Firestore:**

```
db.collection('rooms').doc(roomId).collection('messages').add({
        // ...
        timeStamp: fv.serverTimestamp(),
    });
```

Comment: Look at the update: `const fv = firebase.firestore.fieldValue;`  instead of `const fv = firebaseApp.firestore.fieldValue;`

Comment: Thanks it Worked ... but i still didn't get it. I imported firebase directly from firebase and did the exact same thing and it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

[`FieldValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue)s, such as `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, are sentinel values that can be used when writing document fields with the `set()` or `update()` methods.

If you want to use a timestamp with the `add()` method, you could use [`firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#static-now) instead.

Comment: sorry...Doesn't work...btw thanks for answering

Comment: still showing the same error.. even after using firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()

Comment: Have you tried to log the value of `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` and `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()`? Could you update your question and show us what `db` and `firebase` is?

Comment: ya sure,, I'll add firebase.js file as well to give you a better clarity

Comment: {
nanoseconds: 6000000,
seconds: 1627283655,
}
 this is the log statement of firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()